# SQL count column rows that is dependent on a column in different table when group by

Tags: sql, count, oracle-sqldeveloper

I have been trying to complete the following assignment:

> Write a query that returns authors who've written books in more than one category and whose books are published by at least two different publishers. Display the author's Last Name and First Name, the Titles of Books they've written and the Book type. Sort the output by the author's last name.

These are the tables involved:

```
AUTHORS (Au_id, Au_lname, Au_fname, Phone, Address, City, State, Country, Postalcode) 
PUBLISHERS (Pub_id, Pub_name, City, State) 
TITLES (Title_id, Title, Type, Pub_id, Price, Advance, Total_sales, Notes, Pubdate, Contract) 
TITLEAUTHOR (Au_id, Title_id)
```

I was able to identify the columns I need, but am not sure how to implement the filters (2 different authors, 2 different types).  I assume I need to group by author id and count the Pub_id and Type columns.

This is what I have written so far:

```
SELECT AUTHORS.Au_lname, AUTHORS.Au_fname, TITLE.Title_id, TITLE.Type
from AUTHORS
JOIN TITLEAUTHOR ON AUTHORS.Au_id = TITLEAUTHOR.Au_id
JOIN TITLE ON TITLEAUTHOR.Title_i = TITLE.Title_i 
group by AUTHORS.Au_lname, AUTHORS.Au_fname, TITLE.Title_id, TITLE.Type
ORDER BY AUTHORS.Au_lname;
```

Comment: Note your table column names itself is not matching that in the quer(AUTHORS.AUID)y. Can you create an sqlfiddle?

Comment: sorry i corrected the sql query i was using dummy db  to check it and just... copy paste what is sqlfiddle? sorry i did not mention this but this is school assignment and all we got is the table names and instructions for the query

Comment: http://sqlfiddle.com/ is a website that lets you set up a tiny demo database and query that you can share with other people.  Lots of questions on this site are easier to answer when someone can play around with your dataset and write a query.  [This is a sample](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/dcb16/1) of a SQL Fiddle and query.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Welcome to Stack Overflow, Tomasz!  Congratulations on your first post.  You've done a couple of excellent things already:

- You included details on your schema
- You included a clear problem statement
- You included an example of the SQL you have already tried.

There are a couple of ways you could improve your post, which would help your chances of getting a good answer while also boosting your ability to participate in the community:

- Be very careful with formatting - your second edit introduced some redundant text.
- Be particular with your code - the first set you gave had some incorrect column names, which likely caused some users to look at your post and then ignore it.  There's a critical window after you first post a question where it shows up near the top of the list; that's your best shot at getting answers, so it pays to be very careful with your presentation.  [Here's a link](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to some good reading on how to ask.
- Be upfront about it when you're working on an assignment!  As you can imagine, this community gets a lot of requests for help on homework.  Many of the regular users get frustrated by people looking to 'cheat' on their assignments by posting their homework online. There are ways to get help, though: read [this post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10811/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions) over carefully so you're ready for your next question. The keys are to show that you've already tried to solve it yourself, be specific about what's not working, and be clear about the fact that this is homework.

Now, about your question! What you are looking for is the [`HAVING`](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_having.asp) clause, which allows you to filter a query to return only those members of a group who meet a condition at the aggregate level.  Your instinct about a COUNT was right on, and the HAVING clause will let you do that.  Here's an example:

```
SELECT Au_id
FROM 
    AUTHORS 
     INNER JOIN 
    TITLEAUTHOR ON 
        AUTHORS.Au_id = TITLEAUTHOR.Au_id 
     INNER JOIN 
    TITLES ON 
        TITLEAUTHOR.Title_id = TITLE.Title_id
GROUP BY Au_id 
HAVING 
    COUNT(DISTINCT TITLES.pub_id) > 1 AND 
    COUNT(DISTINCT TITLES.Type) > 1
```

Notice that this adds the word `DISTINCT` inside of the `COUNT()` function - this helps you meet the "two different publishers" requirement.

Once you understand how to use `HAVING`, then you can write a query to get the columns your assignment asked for, and filter the set to only return authors you want:  the basic query structure is going to look like this:

```
SELECT MyColumns
FROM MyTables 
WHERE Au_id IN 
  (
    SELECT Au_id
    FROM 
        AUTHORS 
         INNER JOIN 
        TITLEAUTHOR ON 
            AUTHORS.Au_id = TITLEAUTHOR.Au_id 
         INNER JOIN 
        TITLES ON 
            TITLEAUTHOR.Title_id = TITLE.Title_id
    GROUP BY Au_id 
    HAVING 
        COUNT(DISTINCT TITLES.pub_id) > 1 AND 
        COUNT(DISTINCT TITLES.Type) > 1
  )
ORDER BY WhateverYouWant
```

Good luck, and welcome to SQL!